# passing Callable<T> with parameters

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a Java application that contains a generic module that deducts money from the users wallet.

so the class is as follows:

```
public class BuyGiftForMyselfCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {

private String username;
private long coins;

public BuyGiftForMyselfCallable(final String username,final long coins) {
    this.username=username;
    this.coins=coins;
}

@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {

    ...
    }
```

I want to pass this class to a function that doesn't know about BuyGiftForMyselfCallable. it only knows about Callable!

so I have the following:

```
function receiver(Callable<*> func) {
...
}
```

how in this function I create a new instance of the class and passing parameters to the constructors without it knowing where the class originated from ?

Comment: Shouldn't you create a new instance of the class with proper constructor parameters before passing it to the `receiver` method?

Comment: when you say "how in this function I create a new instance of the class", what **class** do you mean?

Comment: i'm talking about the BuyGiftForMyselfCallable class.  the receiver sits in a generic module that doesn't know of the BuyGiftForMyselfCallable class.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the Callable isn't looking for the type of `BuyGiftForMyselfCallable`, but rather, its return: `Boolean`.

So use `Callable<Boolean>`, I.E.:

```
public void receive(Callable<Boolean> func){
  ...
}
```

Also, you wouldn't be creating the instances of your Callable classes within this function, but creating them elsewhere (constructors and all) - and then passing them into this function.

Comment: Then it doesn't need to be Callable<Boolean>, it just can be generic `Callable<E> func` or even `Callable func`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection [example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) or use `instanceof` to find out what the implementing class is and then do what ever you want with that. But as @vikingsteve mentioned in the comment it's probably a different approach you should use to avoid the necessity of doing that at all